# How to pass a GWT method as a parameter into a Javascript function?

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, jsni

**Overview**

- There is a GWT method called: `private void handleError()`
- There is a JSNI Javascript function called: `private native void registerErrorHandler()`
- The native javascript function calls another function from a third party Javascript library: `foo.attachEvent("EventName", handlerReference);`

**Functionality**

I need to pass the GWT method as a function parameter into the `foo.attachEvent()` function, i tried several approaches:

`foo.attachEvent("Error", registerErrorHandler);` ->
TypeMismatchException

`foo.attachEvent("Error", this.@package.foo::registerErrorHandler());` ->
TypeMismatchException

```
var handler = this.@package.foo::registerErrorHandler()();
foo.attachEvent("Error", handler);
```

->
TypeMismatchException

**Plain Javascript**

When I write this in plain Javascript, it's working:

```
function handleError() {
    alert("Error");
}
function registerErrorHandler() {
    var event = "Error";
    var handler = handleError;

    foo.attachEvent (event, handler);
}
```

How can I implement that into GWT? I am having a lot of problems completely understanding the Javascript - Java Objects conversion. I understand the `handleError` function reference as a `JavaScriptObject`, but I am not able to get it working with that information.

Comment: GWT must be executed within a RootLayoutPanel - This a complete page. You cannot mix Javascript with GWT generated functions. Purpose of GWT is not this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you code needs to look like this: (there are only one time braces, therefore the function is not executed...)

```
var handler = this.@package.foo::registerErrorHandler();
foo.attachEvent("Error", handler);
```

but what you also want to do is wrap your function in the $entry function so that your uncaught exception handler will work:

```
var handler = this.@package.foo::registerErrorHandler();
foo.attachEvent("Error", $entry(handler));
```

What you can always do is build a js function that directly calls your gwt function:

```
var that = this;
var handler = function(){
    that.@package.foo::registerErrorHandler()();
};
foo.attachEvent("Error", $entry(handler));
```

Comment: Thanks for your insight. Your first exampled worked instantly. However, the third party library is not attaching the event somehow, but when I define a new function like in your third example and provide an concrete implementation there (like `$wnd.alert("handled!");`) it's working. If i pass a GWT function with the special syntax, it's not working and somewhere in the gwt code (`__gwt_tearOffGenerators`)an exception is thrown. Do you have an idea for that one, too?

Comment: Ah now i understand the `var that` stuff. It's working. Thanks again.