# How can I pass a java class object from GWT JSNI method?

Tags: gwt, jsni

I have a java class which contain some user basic information now I want to pass this class object from JSNI method

```
 private native void publish(UserInfo userinfo) /*-{
 this.@com.example.my.Class::helloMethod(userinfo;)();
 }-*/
```

how can I achive this task please help me guys .....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass a GWT method as a parameter into a Javascript function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11427970/how-to-pass-a-gwt-method-as-a-parameter-into-a-javascript-function)

Comment: This method is invalid, because you don't specify the type. If it is the only method you could use this notation:     this.@com.example.my.Class::helloMethod(*)(userinfo);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private native void publish(UserInfo userinfo) /*-{
    this.@com.example.client.TestJNSI::helloMethod(Lcom/example/shared/UserInfo;)(userinfo);
}-*/;
```

I hope this is what you are looking for. Make sure to replace example class names with your fully-qualified-class names. For additional information refer [JSNI basic](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html).

Comment: ajax thanks for your response but its showing referencing method unable to resolve

Comment: It wont be possible to address your query without actual code. Make sure method with same signature present in provided scope.